# nginx static content configuration

Tags: linux, nginx, tomcat

I have a server:

```
server {

    listen   80; ## listen for ipv4
    listen   [::]:80 default ipv6only=on; ## listen for ipv6

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/localhost.access.log;


    location ~* \.(png|ico)$ {
         root /home/anatoly/gyazo;
    }

          location / {
            proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:8080;
            proxy_redirect     off;

            proxy_set_header   Host             $host;
            proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }   

}
```

Now my static content (some pictures) is availible on the root of website,
but how can I configure nginx to make static content availible on specific url?
For example website.com/static/*.png

I found  the rewrite command in nginx documentation but I'm not able to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand this correctly, you're looking for [alias](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#alias).

```
location /static/ {
    alias /home/anatoly/gyazo;
}
```

Unless you want to hide non .png and .ico files, this should be perfectly fine.